# Localize i18n Next js _error page

Tags: javascript, next.js, i18next

I want to have a customized _error page for my Next js project. I am using getServerSideProps method for my other pages to localize, but for _error page I am not able to translate the strings, I tried using the getStaticProps method as well, but could not get any different result.

```js
const CustomError = ({ statusCode, hasGetInitialPropsRun, err, pageRootRef }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation(["error", "common"]);
  return (
      <Layout pageRootRef={pageRootRef}>
        <Head>
          <title>{t("title")}</title>
        </Head>
        <div id="_error" className="_error">
          <div className="pt-5 pb-6">
            <div className="max-w max-640">
              <h1 className="mb-2 t-alignC">{t("heading")}</h1>
              <Hairline color="green" />
              <div className="max-w max-128 mb-5">
                <Image
                    src={`${cdnAssetPrefix}/images/pete/pete-confused.png`}
                    className="fit"
                    alt=""
                    width={128}
                    height={137}
                />
              </div>
              <p>
                {t("go-back-paragraph.go-back")}{" "}
                {t("go-back-paragraph.sign-in-again")}
              </p>
              <div className="t-alignC">
                <Link href={LOGIN_URL}>
                  <a className="btn-link btn-xl">
                    {t("go-back-paragraph.go-to-login")}
                  </a>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps({locale}) {
  return {
    props: { ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["error", "common"])) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround in which I redirected the user to a custom error page when an error occurred.

For this to work I first put all my custom error pages into `pages/error/`. I then retrieved the value `accept-language` header of the initial request and compared it to the locales I had defined in my i18n config (I was using [next-translate](https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate)). Finally, I could create a corresponding redirect path based on that information.

```
import i18n from '@/../i18n';
import { Routes } from '@/utils/enums';
import { NextPageContext } from 'next';
import router from 'next/router';

interface ErrorProps {
  statusCode: number;
}

export const ErrorPage = ({ statusCode }: ErrorProps) => {
  return (
    // This will never be rendered because of the getInitialProps
    <p>
      {statusCode
        ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`
        : 'An error occurred on client'}
    </p>
  );
};

ErrorPage.getInitialProps = ({ req, res, err }: NextPageContext) => {
  let redirectPath: string;

  const addErrorCodeToPath = (initialPath: string, statusCode: number) => {
    switch (statusCode) {
      case 404:
        initialPath += Routes.ERROR_404; // "/error/404"
        break;
      case 500:
        initialPath += Routes.ERROR_500; // "/error/500"
        break;
      default:
        initialPath += Routes.ERROR_500;
        break;
    }
    return initialPath;
  };

  if (res) {
    // server
    let locale = '';
    const acceptedLangsHeaderValue = req?.headers['accept-language'];

    if (typeof acceptedLangsHeaderValue === 'string') {
      const acceptedLocales: string[] = [];
      acceptedLocales.push(
        ...acceptedLangsHeaderValue.split(';')[0].split(',')
      );
      locale =
        acceptedLocales.find((acceptedLocale) => {
          return i18n.locales.includes(acceptedLocale.split('-')[0]);
        }) ?? '';
    }

    redirectPath = locale && locale !== i18n.defaultLocale ? `/${locale}` : '/';

    redirectPath = addErrorCodeToPath(redirectPath, res.statusCode);

    res.writeHead(302, {
      Location: redirectPath,
    });
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  // client
  redirectPath = router.locale ? `/${router.locale}` : '';
  redirectPath = addErrorCodeToPath(redirectPath, err?.statusCode ?? 500);
  router.push(redirectPath);
};

export default ErrorPage;
```

This is what `i18n.js` looks like:

```
const i18n = {
  locales: ['de', 'en'],
  defaultLocale: 'de',
  pages: {
    '*': ['common'],
    '/error/404': ['error'],
    '/error/500': ['error'],
  },
};

module.exports = i18n;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue as you, so I solved it like this.

```
// next-i18next.config.js
module.exports = {
    //...
    locales: ['en','zh','de'], // <- here
}
```

Add locales you need as the fourth parameter

```
export async function getStaticProps({locale}) {
    return {
        props: { ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["error", "common"], null, ['en','zh','de'])) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently, Next.js Custom error page - `_error.page` does not support `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` - Link to Docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-error#caveats